# Chrome/Internet explorer browser refresh (F5, ctrl+R, refresh arrow etc.) not working using Angular (2+) project on remote server

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, angular-cli, page-refresh

I have a problem with a simple manual refresh (F5, ctrl+R, refresh arrow etc.) action for a deployed Angular (2+) project on a remote server.

Testing the project locally (development and build prod testet) works perfectly, even when deployed to our intern server, refresh works normally.

On the remote server, any refresh (F5, ctrl+R etc.) is ignored. I get no errors, no page not found, nothing - the browser just stays on the current page with no change or refresh.

In the network tab, it doesn't even send a request to the server.

I can see that the favicon blinks for a millisecond (so something is registered front-end).

The only way I can force the refresh is to change the URL manually.

PS. The only visible differnce is that the remote server runs on https:// protocol.

I have searched for hours on google without any help.

Comment: What do you use for backend? Might be that the CORS is not configured properly.

Comment: May be you have some problem with environment settings in angular application, because you say that no requests are made and also it works fine locally.

Comment: Can you provide some Node or Angular logs? I guess you have the logger in place.

Comment: where are you configuring the routes server or web ?

Comment: Not a CORS problem because the problem is that it's not requesting anything on F5, ctrl+F5 and reload/update buttons. (there is no error). Routes are configured in Angular client-sided.

Comment: please share your link if possible if it deployed on public domain

Comment: Sorry, but project is customer specific and cannot be shared in public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the problem:

The route request was not handled by the server NginX-configuration which resolved in a body-less 204 which Chrome Developer Tools discarded as invalid, making it look like no request was made.

After removing the 204 error-handling, the error showed in Chrome as a 404, so not an Angular problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad router configuration on the angular side is causing a route loop. I would double check your app.module.ts routes. You can also add enableTracing to diagnose the routing:

`{ enableTracing: true }`

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- Add this to debug routes
    )
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have now enabled enableTracing in the routing. When navigating around the application, I see the logs. But when trying the refresh, nothing is logged. I also added an element on the page, that calls location.reload(true); <-- and even this makes no refresh or tracing logs. I will try to reorder the routes configuration pathes.